Simple circuit to charge and balance 7.4v li-ion battery (2s) 2x 3.7v cells in series
I am looking for a simple circuit to charge and balance 7.4v li-ion battery (2s) 2x 3.7v batteries in series, and also with over-charging, discharging, current protection
I have found many circuits based on the TP4056 that can charge a single 3.7v battery. See here for example: (source: https://oshwlab.com/wagiminator/tp4056-lipo-charger-ls)

However, I am having difficulty to find an IC that can charge two 3.7v cells in series (eg. two 18650 cells, or two 600mAh 3.7v cells).
I have seen BMS circuits like the HX-2S-JH20 online (info here), which claims to do cell balancing. But it is a BMS only, and does not do charging. I am looking for something like this that also includes charging:

Any schematic for such a charging and battery protection circuit for 7.4v (2s 3.7v cell) battery with balancing would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.
